# how to code a slideshow with content but no pictures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make a 'slideshow' that has content and a button underneath, when clicked, reveals more content.I've only been able to do css fades which isn't really what i'm after. I shy away from javascript and JQuery because i haven't learnt that yet and am still trying to master css and html.

I can't upload a picture because i lack the reputation, but could you perhaps show me a right path on how to code this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/8g64fabn/ (try it at the bottom right)

Second try: http://jsfiddle.net/8g64fabn/2/

Third update: http://jsfiddle.net/8g64fabn/3/

```html
<div id="content">

    <div>some stuff 1</div>
    <div>some stuff 2</div>
    <div>some stuff 3</div>
    <div>some stuff 4</div>
    <div>some stuff 5</div>

</div>

<button id="showMoreButton">Show more</button>
```

```css
#content > div {
    /*Hide everything*/
    display: none;
}

#content > div:nth-child(1) {
    /*Show first element*/
    display: block;
}
```

```js
//When the #showMoreButton is clicked
$("#showMoreButton").on("click", function () {

    //Get all the elements
    var elems = $("#content > div");

    //Get the visible element
    var visibleElem = elems.filter(":visible");

    //Get next hidden element
    var hiddenElem = visibleElem.next();

    //If there are is no hidden element after current one
    //Can be shortened to if (!hiddenElem.length) {
    if (!hiddenElem.length) {

        //Make hidden element the first hidden element;
        hiddenElem = elems.filter(":first");
    }

    //Hide current visible element
    visibleElem.hide();

    //Show next hidden element
    hiddenElem.show()

});
```

Fade effects and stuff can be added, let me know if you do.

Comment: This is very close to what i want but when the second thing is shown i want the first thing to disappear, is that possible? Thank you so much

Comment: i've been trying but no success. When it goes up to some stuff 5, how do i make it go back to 1? so its a continuous loop, thank you

Comment: you have been nothing but helpful, thank you so much